# Why do cars with 4 drive wheel accelerate faster, from a physics standpoint?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, acceleration

I know that an 4WD car beats a 2WD car "off the line," but I do no understand the physics behind it. I know that:

$$W_{\text{Wheels}} = W_{\text{Engine}} G\,\text{, where } G \text{ is gearing}$$
$$F = \frac{W_W}{r_W}\,\text{, where } r_W \text{ is wheel radius}$$
$$a = \frac{F}{m}$$

I've concluded that:

$$a = \frac{W_E G}{r_W m}$$

And my best guess for factoring in drive wheels, $d$, would be (or symmetrical torque distribution):

$$a =\frac{\frac{W_E G}{d}}{r_W \frac{m}{d}}$$

Attempting to distribute torque and mass among the wheels. But that doesn't change the outcome. I am not taking wind resistance into account on purpose, but I am missing another force? Why, from a physics standpoint, does 4WD accelerate faster than 2WD? How could the above equations be modified to include this variable?

Comment: Hint: Think about how friction between the wheels and the road limits acceleration.

Comment: Plenty of 2WD cars out-accelerate my 4WD truck (except of course on snow/ice/mud).

Comment: So, traction and wheel spin? Less force per wheel means it's "easier" for the tire to regain traction and "apply" its torque to the road?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the example of a 2WD car, in which the front wheels are driven (which is the most common arrangement these days).

When you hit the gas to accelerate the car, there is a countertorque reaction which tends to lift up the front of the car and squat down the rear of it- it is as if the center of mass of the car has shifted towards the back of the car. This unloads the front tires and causes them to slip and spin, which limits the rate at which the car can accelerate.

If the car has all four wheels driven, then the squat tendency pushes the rear wheels into firmer contact with the road and they can push the car forward with less slippage, thereby furnishing better acceleration.

This presupposes that the drive system for the four wheels contains a slip-limiting mechanism which prevents the "spinnage" of the front wheels from short-circuiting the power delivery to the rear wheels. This is called a "limited-slip differential" and it is commonly used in all-wheel-drive cars.

Comment: This answers my question, however I am now curisous about the countertorque mentioned; is there a place I can find more information on this? I have done a few searches and found nothing.

Comment: this is a solved problem in "vehicular dynamics" in the mechanical engineering field. that is where you need to search! -NN